# Drupal Views - Relating 1 Node to N Other Nodes using CCK, NodeReference and Arguments

Tags: drupal, view, arguments, cck, relationship

I am working on a Drupal setup and have run into a slight issue relating nodes together using Views.

Essentially what I want to be able to do, is while editing Node A, have a multiple select node reference field to indicate it is related to Nodes B, C, D. When I view the contents of Node A, it should display the appropriate view for each of those nodes directly on Node A.

I worked through [This Tutorial](http://drupalsn.com/learn-drupal/drupal-tutorials/creating-dynamic-blocks-using-cck-node-reference-and-views-drupal) on using arguments in views, but it seems to be doing things in reverse of what I want. This method requires me to set the relationships in Nodes B, C and D to point to Node A instead of having Node A point to Nodes B, C and D. Setting the relationship in 3 different places instead of 1 location seems counter-intuitive and will be a pain to manage when we start applying this method to a bunch of different nodes.

I selected the following options for the argument:

```
// this is my multiple-select NodeReference relationship field
Content: Linked Highlight Boxes (field_linked_nodes)

Title: [blank]
Breadcrumb: [blank]

Action to take if argument is not present: Provide default argument
Default Argument Type: Node ID from URL

Validator: <Basic Validation>
Action to take if argument does not validate: Hide View / Page not found (404)

Wildcard: all
Wildcard title: All

Allow multiple terms per argument: checked
Exclude the argument: not checked
```

Let me know if you need any more information or explanation. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are going to want the Node Relationships module: http://drupal.org/project/noderelationships. This will give you the back relationships that you want.